# How to Resolve "Procedure could not be found" when loading RCurl in R?

Tags: r, dll, shared-libraries, rcurl

Using R 3.1.1 64-bit in Windows 7, I am unable to load RCurl or any package which depends on RCurl. I have verified the existence of the .dll and other files in the expected location (i.e. the one printed in the error messages).

I opened an issue on Hadley's Github several months ago, but by the time someone responded I had started using another copy of R and the only suggestion was re-installation, which I've done several times.

The errors that I receive are like this:

> require(devtools)
>   Loading required package: devtools
>   Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
>     unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/jmiller/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/RCurl/libs/i386/RCurl.dll':
>     LoadLibrary failure:  The specified procedure could not be found.

and

> require(devtools)
>   Loading required package: devtools
>   Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
>     unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/jmiller/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/RCurl/libs/i386/RCurl.dll':
>     LoadLibrary failure:  The specified procedure could not be found.

Sometimes the errors appear even when only using primitive functions that are completely unrelated to `RCurl`, such as:

```
> require(devtools)
Loading required package: devtools
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/jmiller/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/RCurl/libs/i386/RCurl.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I almost wonder if the problem is somehow with `inDL` instead of `RCurl` but `inDL`?...